# JPA2 how to show fields from table A, table C if table A join table B then join table C?

Tags: java, persistence, jpa-2.0, ejb-3.1

Per subject, I have an entity A, let say with column a1 (PK), a2.
Entity B, with column a2 (PK), b1
Entity C, with column b1 (PK), c1

So A join to B with a2, which then join to C with b1
(They are all one to one relation)

These entities are used in a webservice when upon called will generate an XML file containing a list of these entities.
Now generating a XML combining entity A and B with fields a1, a2, a1 is very simple.

But what is the syntax/annotations needed if I want to generate XML that only shows entity A and entity C? I mean, how do I setup that entity A so it will allow this to happen?

I will also settle if I can get all fields from entity A, B, C.

I'm using jpa2, ejb3.1

**Edit:** Adding examples.

**entity A**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE_A")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "MyComplex.findAll", query = "SELECT j FROM MyComplex j"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "MyComplex.findA1", query = "SELECT j FROM MyComplex j WHERE j.a1 = :A1")
})
public class MyComplex implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "A1", length = 1)
    private String a1;

    @Column(name = "A2", length = 1)
    private String a2;

    public MyComplex() {
    }

    public MyComplex(String a1) {
        this.a1 = a1;
    }

    public String getA1() {
        return a1;
    }

    public void setA1(String a1) {
        this.a1 = a1;
    }

    public String getA2() {
        return a2;
    }

    public void setA2(String a2) {
        this.a2 = a2;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (a1 != null ? a1.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        if (!(object instanceof MyComplex)) {
            return false;
        }
        MyComplex other = (MyComplex) object;
        if ((this.a1 == null && other.a1 != null) || (this.a1 != null && !this.a1.equals(other.a1))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "jpa.mypackage.Table_A[a1=" + a1 + " ]";
    }      
}
```

**entity B**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE_B")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Table_B.findAll", query = "SELECT j FROM Table_B j"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Table_B.findA2", query = "SELECT j FROM Table_B j WHERE j.a2 = :A2")
})
public class Table_B implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "A2", length = 1)
    private String a2;

    @Size(max = 1)
    @Column(name = "B1", length = 1)
    private String b1;

    //entity constructor here

    //entity get/set methods here

    //entity hash methods here      
}
```

**entity C**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE_C")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Table_C.findAll", query = "SELECT j FROM Table_C j"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Table_C.findB1", query = "SELECT j FROM Table_C j WHERE j.b1 = :B1")
})
public class Table_C implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "B1", length = 1)
    private String b1;

    @Size(max = 1)
    @Column(name = "C1", length = 1)
    private String c1;

    //entity constructor here

    //entity get/set methods here

    //entity hash methods here      
}
```

**Modify entity A to join entity B**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE_A")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "MyComplex.findAll", query = "SELECT j FROM MyComplex j"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "MyComplex.findA1", query = "SELECT j FROM MyComplex j WHERE j.a1 = :A1")
})
public class MyComplex implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "A1", length = 1)
    private String a1;

    @Column(name = "A2", length = 1)
    private String a2;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="A2", referencedColumnName="A2")
    private Table_B table_B;

    //entity constructor here

    //entity get/set methods here
    public Table_B getTable_B() {
        return table_B;
    }

    public void setTable_B(Table_B table_B) {
        this.table_B = table_B;
    }    

    //entity hash methods here  
}
```

Comment: Without code sample it is hard to give an exact answer. I can only suggest you create a wrapper entity that contains only the column needed and populate this (list of) wrapper entity, then feed it ot the web-service

Comment: @JScoobyCed Do you mean creating a jpa native query (via createNativeQuery), call it and populate the wrapper entity with all the fields?

Comment: I cannot choose this way because the actual entity links to 5-6 other entities which total up to hundreds of fields. Any further changes will be made difficult. Not to mention that native query will be awfully long and hard to maintain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your figure, I see Table_B is just a join table for A and C. If you set up OneToOne annotation with JoinTable in MyComplex.java, then I believe you can setup Table_A and Table_C relationship.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE_A")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "MyComplex.findAll", query = "SELECT j FROM MyComplex j"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "MyComplex.findA1", query = "SELECT j FROM MyComplex j WHERE j.a1 = :A1")
})
public class MyComplex implements Serializable {
/* ------------------------------------ */
@OneToOne
@JoinTable(
        name="Table_B",
        joinColumns=
            @JoinColumn(name="A2", referencedColumnName="A2"),
        inverseJoinColumns=
            @JoinColumn(name="B1", referencedColumnName="B1")
    )
private Table_C tableC;
/* ------------ */
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tested the code originally but Netbean/eclipselink was complaining something about reference/mapping "does not correspond to a valid field on the mapping reference"... Somehow I copy the netbean project under a new name and redeploy to glassfish, fail due to the common memory issue... After server restart I've redeploy the project and it successfully show all info needed. I still not sure why the same code failed originally with an error but success later after server restart...

Comment: 'reference/mapping "does not correspond to a valid field on the mapping reference' ?? Mostly, it is because of missing or invalid entity definitions at persistences.xml